# Dates for travel to Antarctica in local spring

Tags: antarctica

While some Antarctic stations have a permanent crew, for most people who visit the continent, whether as workers or tourists, travel starts in southern-hemisphere spring.

In what date range would summer workers normally travel to Antarctica? (I'm specifically interested in Showa Station, but also in answers for any of the other stations.)

Comment: Are you asking with a mind to working there?  If so, this question will be better answered on our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exact times will vary by location and weather, but for most stations, the first flights in might be in mid- to late-October, and the last flights out in perhaps late March. Note that not all summer staff will travel down right at the start of the season - a lot of them will still be arriving into December.

Somewhere deep inland might have a somewhat shorter season - I think last flights out of Amundsen-Scott at the South Pole are usually end of February/start of March, for example.

Ship travel is a bit more unpredictable and would likely have a narrower window of start/end dates (the very *last* thing you want is a ship stuck at the end of the summer season).